# Movie about a cop slowing down time

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to recall a movie I used to watch as a kid (this wasn't a kids movie however). It was from the 80's because I watched it in the early 90's.

The main character was a guy in a trench coat, who wasn't old but had grey hair and throughout the movie they make reference to his age. I believe he was some kind of cop or agent. This movie was kind of futuristic, but not really sci-fi.

Around the middle of the movie he ends up with a young and beautiful girl and helps her out. Of course, they fall in love.

The trick of the movie was that the trench coat guy had a device that could stop or slow down time like if someone was shooting at him, he could slow time and get away. But it only lasted a short time. It might have been a watch.

There were bad guys and they looked like normal people except when the trench coat guy was around, their faces turned out to look like they were burned or something. When they died, they would disappear in a blue light and leave a burn mark on the floor/ground.

One scene I recall is the trench coat guy went to a type of tanning salon and the young guy working there was a bad guy and locked him in one of these tanning rooms where he was getting burned. The bad guy blocked the door with a surf board.

In another, the trench coat guy and the girl were getting intimate when some young girl came on the TV and started telling him what to do. This girl was like his boss or commander or something.

Color, English and from what I recall was not a B movie (did they have B movies back then?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like [Trancers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trancers), (1985).  The trench-coat guy, Jack Deth, (Tim Thomerson), has white hair.  The young beautiful girl is played by young Helen Hunt.

> Deth can identify a tranced victim by scanning them with a special
>   bracelet. All trancers appear as normal humans at first, but once
>   triggered, they become **savage killers with twisted features**.
>
> ...
>
> People can travel back in time by injecting themselves with a drug
>   which allows them to take over the body of an ancestor. When Jack Deth
>   arrives in 1985, he is in the body of his ancestor, a journalist;
>   Whistler assumes control of his ancestor, a police detective; and
>   Deth's supervisor, McNulty, borrows the form of his own forebear, **a
>   young girl.**
>
> ...
>
> Deth is given some high-tech equipment which is sent to him in the
>   past: his sidearm, (which contains two hidden vials of time drugs to
>   send him and Whistler back to the future), and a "long-second"
>   wristwatch, which temporarily **slows time stretching one second to ten**.

Comment: Holy crap that's it and not only does Netflix have it, they have a part 2!

Comment: I always felt that "Jack Deth" was the perfect name for an action movie hero.